# How to dispatch outside of class component in reactjs / redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, antd

I'm struggling to understand a concept here i think related to scope and can't put my finger on how to do this.

I'm working on a class component involving redux and antd's table functionality.
The table displays fine so that's good. It's pulling in the data from my store and displaying it properly. Here is what it looks like. Note in particular the "Archive" action button at the right which relates to my question.

[image: My table]

I decided to use antd's popconfirm tag such that if someone clicks the archive link, they get an additional confirmation dialog. That also works fine. The dialog pops up and i can click yes/no and the corresponding function gets called. **My problem is now getting the property to actually update in my redux store.** What i'd like it to do is to update the particular property's "archive" (to true) and "archivedate" (to current date) fields in redux if someone proceeds to confirm the popup dialog.

The function in particular where this should happen (ignore the comments. i was trying to update the object):

```
function confirm(record, e) {
  message.success('Archived');
  // const archived = true;
  console.log("confirm function.. record")
  // setState(() => ({ archived }));
  // record.archived = false;
  // record.archiveddate = moment();
  console.log(record);
}
```

Through console.log i can see that within my confirm function, I do indeed have access to the particular property (or "record" above) object (e.g. property.id, property.archived, property.archiveddate). I figure that's important to dispatch the right property id. But i'm not sure what to put inside the confirm function to get this done. In part i think this is because the function is not within the class component and therefore i can't simply do a props.archiveProperty like i otherwise would be able to thanks to the mapdistpatchtoprops.

So in summary, something about antd's table method of making me define this data structure for columns and rows (and functions) outside the class component is messing with my (lack of?) understanding on how scope works here and how to ultimately update my property.

appreciate any guidance!

The entire js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import selectProperties from '../selectors/properties';
import { startEditProperty } from '../actions/properties';
import { Table, Tag, Divider, Popconfirm, message } from 'antd';
import moment from 'moment';

const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Address',
    dataIndex: 'street',
    key: 'street',
    render: text => <a>{text}</a>,
  },
  {
    title: 'City',
    dataIndex: 'city',
    key: 'city',
  },
  {
    title: 'State',
    dataIndex: 'state',
    key: 'state',
  },
  {
    title: 'Workflow',
    key: 'workflow',
    dataIndex: 'workflow',
    sorter: (a, b) => a.workflow.length - b.workflow.length,
    sortDirections: ['descend'],
    render: workflow => {
      let color = 'geekblue';
      if (workflow === 'Inspection' || workflow === 'Maintenance' || workflow === 'Cleaning') {
        color = 'volcano';
      }
      else if (workflow === 'Rented') {
        color = 'green';
      }
      return (
        <span>
          <Tag color={color} key={workflow}>
             {workflow.toUpperCase()}
          </Tag>
        </span>
      );
    },
  },
  {
    title: 'Action',
    key: 'action',
    render: (text, record) => (
      <span>
        <a>Edit</a>
        <Divider type="vertical" />
        <Popconfirm
          title="Are you sure?"
          onConfirm={confirm.bind(this, record)}
          onCancel={cancel}
          okText="Yes"
          cancelText="No"
        >
          <a href="#">Archive</a>
        </Popconfirm>
      </span>
    ),
  },
];

function confirm(record, e) {
  message.success('Archived');
  // const archived = true;
  console.log("confirm function.. record")
  // setState(() => ({ archived }));
  // record.archived = false;
  // record.archiveddate = moment();
  console.log(record);
}

function cancel(e) {
  console.log(e);
  message.error('Cancelled');
}

export class PropertyList extends React.Component {
  // onSubmit = (property) => {
  //   this.props.archiveProperty(this.props.property.id, property);
  //   this.props.history.push('/');
  // };
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="content-container">
            <div className="list-body">
            {
                this.props.properties.length === 0 ? (
                <div className="list-item list-item--message">
                    <span>No properties. Add some!</span>
                </div>

                ) : (
                <Table rowKey="id" dataSource={this.props.properties} columns={columns} pagination = { false } footer={() => ''} />
                )
            }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log("PropertyList mapStateToProps..");
  console.log(state);
  return {
    properties: selectProperties(state.properties, state.filters)
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  archiveProperty: (id, property) => dispatch(startEditProperty(id, property))
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PropertyList);
```

Answer (score 1):

First your dispatch will be like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  archiveProperty: (id, property) => dispatch('your_type',{id, property})
});
```

Considering that you are getting the `record` that you want to update to archive and i am hoping that will have `id` property.
So, in `confirm` method you have to dispatch the event that you have already defined like this:

```
function confirm(record, e) {
    message.success('Archived');
    console.log(record);
    this.props.archiveProperty(record.id,record);
}
```

And your flag changing logic will be in reducer like this:

```
  [your_type]:(state,action)=>{
      // in action you will get your data that you have passed from dispatch event
      //your logic goes here
      //after your logic,return updated state
  }
```

See you updated js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import selectProperties from '../selectors/properties';
import { startEditProperty } from '../actions/properties';
import { Table, Tag, Divider, Popconfirm, message } from 'antd';
import moment from 'moment';

const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Address',
    dataIndex: 'street',
    key: 'street',
    render: text => <a>{text}</a>,
  },
  {
    title: 'City',
    dataIndex: 'city',
    key: 'city',
  },
  {
    title: 'State',
    dataIndex: 'state',
    key: 'state',
  },
  {
    title: 'Workflow',
    key: 'workflow',
    dataIndex: 'workflow',
    sorter: (a, b) => a.workflow.length - b.workflow.length,
    sortDirections: ['descend'],
    render: workflow => {
      let color = 'geekblue';
      if (workflow === 'Inspection' || workflow === 'Maintenance' || workflow === 'Cleaning') {
        color = 'volcano';
      }
      else if (workflow === 'Rented') {
        color = 'green';
      }
      return (
        <span>
          <Tag color={color} key={workflow}>
             {workflow.toUpperCase()}
          </Tag>
        </span>
      );
    },
  },
  {
    title: 'Action',
    key: 'action',
    render: (text, record) => (
      <span>
        <a>Edit</a>
        <Divider type="vertical" />
        <Popconfirm
          title="Are you sure?"
          onConfirm={confirm.bind(this, record)}
          onCancel={cancel}
          okText="Yes"
          cancelText="No"
        >
          <a href="#">Archive</a>
        </Popconfirm>
      </span>
    ),
  },
];



export class PropertyList extends React.Component {
  // onSubmit = (property) => {
  //   this.props.archiveProperty(this.props.property.id, property);
  //   this.props.history.push('/');
  // };
  confirm = (record, e) => {
    message.success('Archived');
    console.log("confirm function.. record");
    console.log('make sure you are getting recird with all details:',record);
    this.props.archiveProperty(record.id,record);
  }

  cancel = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    message.error('Cancelled');
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="content-container">
            <div className="list-body">
            {
                this.props.properties.length === 0 ? (
                <div className="list-item list-item--message">
                    <span>No properties. Add some!</span>
                </div>

                ) : (
                <Table rowKey="id" dataSource={this.props.properties} columns={columns} pagination = { false } footer={() => ''} />
                )
            }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log("PropertyList mapStateToProps..");
  console.log(state);
  return {
    properties: selectProperties(state.properties, state.filters)
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  archiveProperty: (id, property) => dispatch('your_type',{id, property})
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PropertyList);
```

I moved your confirm function in component.
Let me know if this worked.

Comment: I get a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined" on the "this.props.archiveProperty(record.id,record);" line. I was assuming because the function exists outside the class component but admit i could missunderstanding the error.

Comment: Yes,move it into your component.
And either you have to bind your confirm in constructor or use an arrow function.

Or in constructor:

`this.confirm  = this.confirm.bind(this);`

Arrow function:
`confirm = (record,e) =>{your logic}`

Comment: hmm trying the arrow function route had no effect and still results in "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined". i.e.:
`confirm = (record, e) => {
  message.success('Archived');
  console.log("confirm function.. record")
  console.log(record);
  this.props.archiveProperty(record.id, record);
}`

Comment: i'm not really sure how to handle the constructor suggestion. I tried: 
`export class PropertyList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.confirm = this.confirm.bind(this);
  }`
which results in a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined"

Comment: You need to move your function in class component.Did you move and then tried?After moving function,any of the approach will work.

Comment: I don't think that I understand what you're suggesting.

Comment: I have updated my answer.See your full file code in answer.

Comment: After moving those two functions into the class it does compile but when refreshing the page in the chrome console it complains "Uncaught ReferenceError: cancel is not defined" referring to the `onCancel={cancel}` line above in the columns object under Actions->Popconfirm.

Comment: Just like you have bound confirm,bind cancel as well and try.

Comment: as in `onConfirm={confirm.bind(this, record)}
          onCancel={cancel.bind}`? same error. Uncaught ReferenceError: cancel is not defined".

Comment: Main thing in react is if you want to use any thing from component,it should be in component only.Put columns in components then only you will be able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and best way to achieve it.

```js
import store from 'your_store_path_here';

store.dispatch(someAction)
```